# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus in Complex Analyis. [Existence of the antiderivative]

Tags: complex-analysis

In the real case $f \in C(I)$ on interval $I = [a,b]$  (The $C(I)$ means set of the continuos functions on the $I$)

Then by F.T.C$(1)$ , $\exists F : I \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(x) = \int_I f dx $ s.t. $F'(x) = f(x)$ (I.e. Existence of the anti-derivative)

Suddenly the complex case crossed my mind, So I made the statement.

**statement(*))** $f \in C(D)$ on simply connected $D$  (The $C(D)$ means set of the continuos functions on the $D$)

Then,  $\exists F : D \to \mathbb{C}$ by $F(z) = \int f dz $ s.t. $F'(z) = f(z)$(I.e. Existence of the anti-derivative)

---

Well It looks like a true only depending on the intuitive thought. But all we knew that to claim the existence of the $F$(anti-derivative of the $f$), we need two condition that not only  the one "$f$ is analytic on $D$" but also the other "$D$ is a simply connected." Plus I found the counterexample that $f(z) = \vert z \vert $. (The $f(z) = \vert z \vert$ surely continuous on simply connected $\mathbb{C}$ plane. By the way $f(z)$ doesn't have primitive since it is not analytic.)
So my conclusion is **(*)** is false statement.

But still I don't have any confidence my thought right or not. Would you say your thought for me?

Any help and answer would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following, we'll take the term *analytic* to mean *complex differentiable*.

Your statement (*) is not true. If $F\colon D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is an analytic function, automatically, all of its derivatives (in the complex sense and not only in the real sense) exist, therefore $F'$ is again an analytic function on $D$.

Suppose, for the moment, that $D=\mathbb{D}$ denotes the unit disk.
Your statement (*) would imply that some continuous functions in $\mathbb{D}$ are, in fact, analytic. We could take, for example, a [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function), which is non-zero and continuous but since it's identically zero on a non-empty open region (namely the area between the bump and the boundary of $\mathbb{D}$), the [identity theorem for analytic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) tells us that it is impossible for such a function to be analytic in $\mathbb{D}$ and therefore, it is impossible for such function to have an analytic primitive in the complex sense (in $\mathbb{D}$).

The bump function is a good example. We're talking about a non-zero infinitely differentiable function (in the real sense) which is identically zero outside of a compact set, something that is completely impossible in the complex case since such function would be identically zero. This shows how special complex differentiation is compared to the real case.

Now, the *simply connected* part of (*) is a more delicate one. If we have an *analytic* function $f\colon D\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, the fact that $D$ is simply connected helps us construct the analytic primitive $F$. Take some point $z_0\in D$ and define
$$
  F(z)=\int_{\gamma_z} f(\zeta)\,d\zeta
  ,
$$
where $\gamma_z$ is some curve in $D$ which connects $z_0$ with $z$. The first thing that comes to mind is: how do we know that such $F$ is well-defined? The answer comes when we
remember that $D$ is simply connected. You can find all the details in any introductory text of complex analysis (I hope). (For example: Lang, Ahlfors...) Showing that $F$ satisfies $F'=f$ in all of $D$ is then no complicated task.

---

Edit: I forgot to mention but, the fact that $f$ is analytic will help us prove that $F'=f$  in all of $D$.

---

Your example $z\mapsto |z|$ is pretty good as well, since, as you pointed out, we're talking about a continuous function which is not analytic and hence cannot have an analytic primitive. I hope this helped.

---

In this discussion we used two important facts about analytic functions of a complex variable:

1. If a function is complex differentiable then it is infinitely complex differentiable.
2. The identity theorem for analytic functions.